Is there any http header that an http server can use to communicate the maximum request size to an http client?
I have looked all over for this and cannot find an answer so please forgive me if my Google-Fu is just failing me.
I currently working with http servers and I was trying to find a protocol-based or other standards-based way to communicate to a client what the maximum HTTP request size was but it doesn't appear as though such a thing exists.
I was looking for something similar to a Content-Length header. Maybe something like Max-Content-Length?
If this kind of thing truly doesn't exist, what would you say is the reason that it doesn't exist yet?
Really appreciate your help!

It's not difficult to trust yourself that no such thing exists yet. Web servers usually return 40x errors (400 or 404 are all possible up to the web server vendors) to the browsers and tell that they cannot serve large requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413

I guess you can use OPTIONS method to run a pre-flight check, but I'm not sure the information itself is standardised.

@ÁlvaroGonzález That's the direction my research was taking me, but I wanted to touch base with other human professionals and make sure I wasn't doing something ridiculously ignorant. Thank you!
